# how can I access my json encoded data from PHP into a mysql query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I have been on a long mission here, I have gotten to my last step in my program and I can't seem to figure out how to crack open a JSON string from my Ajax request sent to my PHP.

My Jquery code looks like this;

```
$('#formElem').submit(function(){
    var data = {};
    $("input[name=scene]").each(function() {
        data[$(this).val()] = {
            scene: $(this).val(),
            int_text: $(this).next("input[name=int_ext]").val(),
            desc: $(this).next().next("input[name=scene_desc]").val(),
            day_night: $(this).next().next().next("input[name=day_night]").val()
        };
    });
    $.post("script.import.php", {
    action: 'save-import',
    data: data // as-is
    //data: JSON.stringify(data) // with stringify
    }, function(resp) {
    console.log(eval('('+resp.scene+')'));
    console.log(eval(resp.int_ext));
    console.log(eval(resp.desc));
    console.log(resp.day_night);
    });
    return false;
});
```

and my PHP is:

```
if($_POST['save-import']){
    $scenes = json_decode($_POST['data']);
    echo($scenes);
}
```

A snippet of what my JSON response looks like:

```
WITHOUT stringify()
action  save-import
data[100][day_night]    NIGHT
data[100][desc] SAPNA'S BEDROOM
data[100][int_text] INT
data[100][scene]    100
data[101][day_night]    NIGHT
data[101][desc] LIVING ROOM
data[101][int_text] INT
data[101][scene]    101
data[102][day_night]    NIGHT
data[102][desc] SHAH HOUSE, FRONT YARD
data[102][int_text] EXT
data[102][scene]    102
data[103][day_night]    NIGHT
data[103][desc] SHAH HOUSE, FRONT PORCH
data[103][int_text] EXT

WITH stringify()
    {"2":{"scene":"2","int_text":"INT","desc":"SAPNA'S BEDROOM","day_night":"MORNING"},"9":{"scene":"9","int_text":"INT","desc":"BMW","day_night":"NIGHT"},"19":{"scene":"19","int_text":"INT","desc":"SAPNA'S BEDROOM","day_night":"DAY"},"21":{"scene":"21","int_text":"INT","desc":"KITCHEN","day_night":"DAY"},"22":{"scene":"22","int_text":"INT","desc":"HALLWAY","day_night":"DAY"},"23":{"scene":"23","int_text":"INT","desc":"TEMPLE ROOM","day_night":"DAY"},"24":{"scene":"24","int_text":"INT","desc":"LIVING ROOM","day_night":"NIGHT"}
```

when the ajax is sent to my php to get processed i need to be able to break apart the json response to accomplish this query

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO (`project_id`, `scene`, `int_ext`, `scene_desc`, `day_night`)
             VALUES ('10', 'data.scene', 'data.int_ext', 'data.desc', 'data.day_night')");
```

what the JSON should read in english is

```
scene: 24
int_ext: "INT"
desc: "LIVING ROOM"
day_night: "NIGHT"
```

as one query, and do to that for every scene in the JSON string.

EDIT:

```
with var_dump
string(11463) ""{\\\"2\\\":{\\\"scene\\\":\\\"2\\\",\\\"int_text\\\":\\\"INT\\\",\\\"desc\\\":\\\"SAPNA\\'S BEDROOM\\\",\\\"day_night\\\":\\\"MORNING\\\"},\\\"9\\\":{\\\"scene\\\":\\\"9\\\",\\\"int_text\\\":\\\"INT\\\",\\\"desc\\\":\\\"BMW\\\",\\\"day_night\\\":\\\"NIGHT\\\"},\\\"19\\\":{\\\"scene\\\":\\\"19\\\",\\\"int_text\\\":\\\"INT\\\",\\\"desc\\\":\\\"SAPNA\\'S BEDROOM\\\",\\\"day_night\\\":\\\"DAY\\\"},\\\"21\\\":{\\\"scene\\\":\\\"21\\\",\\\"int_text\\\":\\\"INT\\\",\\\"desc\\\":\\\"KITCHEN\\\",\\\"day_night\\\":\\\"DAY\\\"},\\\"22\\\":{\\\"scene\\\":\\\"22\\\",\\\"int_text\\\":\\\"INT\\\",\\\"desc\\\":\\\"HALLWAY\\\",\\\"day_night\\\":\\\"DAY\\\"},\\\"23\\\":{\\\"scene\\\":\\\"23\\\",\\\"int_text\\\":\\\"INT\\\",\\\"desc\\\":\\\"TEMPLE ROOM\\\",\\\"day_night\\\":\\\"DAY\\\"},\\\"24\\\":{\\\"scene\\\":\\\"24\\\",\\\"int_text\\\":\\\"INT\\\",\\\"desc\\\":\\\"LIVING ROOM\\\",\\\"day_night\\\":\\\"NIGHT\\\"},\\\"26\\\":{\\\"scene\\\":\\\"26\\\",\\\"int_text\\\":\\\"INT\\\",\\\"desc\\\":\\\"TREE HOUSE\\\",\\\"day_night\\\":\\\"NIGHT\\\"}
```

EDIT: with stripslashes

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /home/content/06/5679006/html/v3/test.php on line 4
```

Comment: In your php, replace echo ($scenes); with var_dump($scenes); and post what that gives you.

Comment: @Stephen I edit with a var_dump

Comment: what does the data look like when you convert it to a natural array as opposed to a object? e.g. json_decode($_POST['data'],true);

Comment: i tried that already, i wasn't able to access the associative array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me. Apparently there is really something going wrong with the slashes there:

```
$json = <<<JSON
    {\\\"2\\\":{\\\"scene\\\":\\\"2\\\",\\\"int_text\\\":\\\"INT\\\",\\\"desc\\\":\\\"SAPNA\\'S BEDROOM\\\",\\\"day_night\\\":\\\"MORNING\\\"},\\\"9\\\":{\\\"scene\\\":\\\"9\\\",\\\"int_text\\\":\\\"INT\\\",\\\"desc\\\":\\\"BMW\\\",\\\"day_night\\\":\\\"NIGHT\\\"},\\\"19\\\":{\\\"scene\\\":\\\"19\\\",\\\"int_text\\\":\\\"INT\\\",\\\"desc\\\":\\\"SAPNA\\'S BEDROOM\\\",\\\"day_night\\\":\\\"DAY\\\"},\\\"21\\\":{\\\"scene\\\":\\\"21\\\",\\\"int_text\\\":\\\"INT\\\",\\\"desc\\\":\\\"KITCHEN\\\",\\\"day_night\\\":\\\"DAY\\\"},\\\"22\\\":{\\\"scene\\\":\\\"22\\\",\\\"int_text\\\":\\\"INT\\\",\\\"desc\\\":\\\"HALLWAY\\\",\\\"day_night\\\":\\\"DAY\\\"},\\\"23\\\":{\\\"scene\\\":\\\"23\\\",\\\"int_text\\\":\\\"INT\\\",\\\"desc\\\":\\\"TEMPLE ROOM\\\",\\\"day_night\\\":\\\"DAY\\\"},\\\"24\\\":{\\\"scene\\\":\\\"24\\\",\\\"int_text\\\":\\\"INT\\\",\\\"desc\\\":\\\"LIVING ROOM\\\",\\\"day_night\\\":\\\"NIGHT\\\"},\\\"26\\\":{\\\"scene\\\":\\\"26\\\",\\\"int_text\\\":\\\"INT\\\",\\\"desc\\\":\\\"TREE HOUSE\\\",\\\"day_night\\\":\\\"NIGHT\\\"}}
JSON;

$json = stripslashes(stripslashes($json));

$data = json_decode($json);

foreach($data as $item) {
    /*
    Item looks like this:
    stdClass Object
            (
                [scene] => 2
                [int_text] => INT
                [desc] => SAPNA'S BEDROOM
                [day_night] => MORNING
            )
    */
}
```

Comment: OH, how can I just use my $_POST['data'] variable?

Comment: Just say $json = $_POST['data'], for example.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the var_dump you posted, try this:

```
if($_POST['save-import']){
    $scenes = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
    echo($scenes);
}
```

Looks like something is going a little crazy with escaping the JSON object before it gets transmitted.

Comment: I added it to the bottom of the original post